# Set values in an array within an object

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I've got an issue with an Object array in an object:

I have a class with an object array:

```
class element
{
public:
element() {};
LinePiece* arrayLP;
```

and I have a class thats in the array:

```
class LinePiece
{
public:
LinePiece() {};

AnsiString Type;
int ElementNr;
int Status;
int X, Y;
```

so within the Element object I have a LinePiece array. The odd thing is, when I fill in ElementArray[1].LPArray[0]; it gets overwritten by the next object (ElementArray[2].LPArray[0];

I fill it with the following code:

```
String FileBuffer;
String Regel;
String Code;

element* GetElementInfo()
{
//alle onderdelen van een Elementobject
String OrderNumber;             //ON
String OrderBrand;              //MO
String ElementNumber;           //SN
String ElementMarking;          //RS
String ReinforcementPattern;    //OW
String CalculationNumber;       //CN
String ElementLength;           //LE
String ElementWidth;            //WD
String ElementBeginX;           //BP
String ConcreteThickness;       //TH
String Isulation;               //IH
String Weight;                  //NW

element *ElementArray = new element[100];
LinePiece *LPArray = new LinePiece[100];
bool firstElement = true;
int Index =0;
int LPIndex = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= FileBuffer.Length(); i++)
{
    if(FileBuffer[i] != 0)
    {
        if(FileBuffer[i] != IntToStr('\r'))  //controleren of je op einde regel zit, zoniet vul de string "regel" aan
        {
            if(FileBuffer[i] != IntToStr('\r') && FileBuffer[i] != IntToStr('\n'))
            {
                Regel = Regel + FileBuffer[i];
            }
        }
        else //kijken wat er op de regel staat
        {
            Code = Regel.SubString(0,2);

            if(Code == "ON") //Ordernummer
            {
                OrderNumber = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length() -3));
                Regel = "";
            }
            if(Code =="MO")  //Ordermerk
            {
                 OrderBrand = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length() -3));
                 Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code =="SN")  //Element nummer
            {
                ElementNumber = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code =="RS") //Element marking
            {
                ElementMarking = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code =="CN") //Calculatienummer
            {
                CalculationNumber = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code == "LE") //Element lengte
            {
                ElementLength = Regel.SubString(4,(Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code == "WD") //element breedte
            {
                ElementWidth = Regel.SubString(4,(Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code == "BP") //beginpunt X
            {
                ElementBeginX = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }
            if (Code == "OW") //Wapeningspatroon
            {
                ReinforcementPattern = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }
            if(Code == "TH")  //Beton dikte
            {
                ConcreteThickness = Regel.SubString(4,(Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code == "IH") //isolatie dikte
            {
                Isulation = Regel.SubString(4,(Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code == "NW")  //Gewicht
            {
                Weight = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length()-3));
                Regel = "";
            }

            if(Code == "CO") //Contour
            {
                String geheleRegel = Regel.SubString(4, (Regel.Length() -3));

                int EleNr = 0;
                int Status = 0;
                //geheleRegel doormidden hakken voor x en y waardes.
                String X = geheleRegel.SubString(0, (geheleRegel.Length() /2));
                String Y = geheleRegel.SubString(geheleRegel.Length()/2 +1, geheleRegel.Length());

                LinePiece lpObject(Code, EleNr, Status, StrToInt(X), StrToInt(Y));
                LPArray[LPIndex] = lpObject;
                LPIndex++;
                Regel = "";
            }


            if(Code == "*" && firstElement == false) //Nieuw element
            {
                if(OrderNumber == "")
                {
                    OrderNumber =="-";
                }

                if(OrderBrand == "")
                {
                    OrderBrand = "-";
                }

                if(ElementNumber == "")
                {
                    ElementNumber = "-";
                }

                if(ElementMarking == "")
                {
                    ElementMarking = "-";
                }

                if (ReinforcementPattern == "")
                {
                    ReinforcementPattern = "-";
                }

                if (CalculationNumber == "")
                {
                    CalculationNumber = "-";
                }

                if(ElementLength == "")
                {
                    ElementLength = 0;
                }

                if(ElementWidth == "")
                {
                    ElementWidth = 0;
                }

                if(ElementBeginX == "")
                {
                    ElementBeginX = 0;
                }

                if(ConcreteThickness == "")
                {
                    ConcreteThickness = 0;
                }

                if(Isulation == "")
                {
                    Isulation = 0;
                }

                if(Weight == "")
                {
                    Weight = 0;
                }

                element ElementObject(OrderNumber, OrderBrand, ElementNumber, ElementMarking,
                ReinforcementPattern, CalculationNumber, StrToInt(ElementLength), StrToInt(ElementWidth),
                StrToInt(ElementBeginX), StrToInt(ConcreteThickness),StrToInt(Isulation),
                Weight, LPArray);

                ElementArray[Index] = ElementObject;
                LPIndex = 0;    /resetting LPIndex
                Index++;
            }
            else  
            {
                Regel="";
            }

            if (Code == "*")
            {
                 firstElement = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
return ElementArray;
}
```

So for some reason, it doesn't make 'X' different LPArrays, but overwrites all the LParrays with the last one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you just allocate a single `LinePiece` array and use it for every `element`? Also, you'd be better using `std::vector` instead of dynamic arrays.

Comment: can you post the complete code including the loops? I think it's confusing that way.

Comment: Yes, I'm just using 1 `LinePiece` array and just refill it for every new object. That shouldn't be a problem when I fill the `ElementObject` with the `LinePiece`array first?

Comment: @Bart if you use the same array for every element, of course modifying one will change the others, it's the same array.

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid added the whole code.@TartanLlama If I do that with an int (for example OrderNumber) it gives different numbers... why doesn't it work for the object array?

Comment: element::arrayLP is not used in your code

Comment: `ElementArray[1].LPArray[0];` this is wrong, you should have `ElementArray[1].arrayLP [0];` and arrayLP should be initialized like in my answer

Comment: @Bart arrays are not copied when you pass them around. If you want an array with value semantics you can use `std::array` in C++11. I don't know if the `100` elements is just an arbitrary size or not, but if it is, you should use `std::vector` instead to get a dynamic, resizeable collection.

Comment: @TartanLlama Yeah, I will look into the vector part. Thanks for the tip and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization code should looks like:

```
element *ElementArray = new element[100];
for ( int n = 0; n < 100; ++n )
  ElementArray[n].arrayLP = new LinePiece[100];
```

so the behaviour you describe might be due to undefined bahaviour

you dont seem to delete your allocated array anywhere - that will cause memory leaks. Also if you want arrays and not vectors then you must obey rule of three (add copy constructor/operator and destructor).

Comment: @Bart instead of `LinePiece*` add `std::vector<LinePiece>` and the same for ElementArray. Then use `ElementArray.resize(100)` and `for ( int n = 0; n < ElementArray.size(); ++n ) ElementArray[n].arrayLP.resize(100);`.

Comment: And what if I want to keep the vectors dynamically? Like I dont want to give them an size?

Comment: you can call `resize(newSize)` on vector any time you want.